# Timers in Android Studio using CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer, countdowntimer

See I'm trying to get User input for time and using the user input trying to run the CountDownTimer function in Android studio 4.2.2

The problem is :-

### case-1

**when I pass Variable name in place of millisInFuture** attribute of countDown timer function and trying to set textview accordingly , the **TextView doesn't get set up anything**.

```
public void timer() {
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(**timeValueIntent**, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //  mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                //mediaPlayer.start();
                timerValueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "s");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                restartButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                restartButton.setEnabled(true);
                quitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setBtnCond(true);
                //mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        }.start();
    }`
```

### case-2

But **when I pass int value like 1000 etc in millisInFuture** attribute of CountDownTimer and set up the textView , **it gets successfully set up.**

```
public void timer() {
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(**300000**, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //  mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                //mediaPlayer.start();
                timerValueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "s");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                restartButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                restartButton.setEnabled(true);
                quitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setBtnCond(true);
                //mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        }.start();
    }`
```

Can anyone ***please help to let me pass variable name instead of a hardcoded integer value in MillisInFuture*** attribute of CountDownTimer function.!!?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some source code similar to your questions just implement your project.

**Init Variables**

```
private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 600000;
private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
private Button mButtonStartPause;
private Button mButtonReset;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
private boolean mTimerRunning;
private long mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
```

**onCreate**

```
//Init
    mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
    mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
    mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
    mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mTimerRunning) {
                pauseTimer();       //pauseFunction
            } else {
                startTimer();       //StartFunction
            }
        }
    });



mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();       // resetFunction
            }
        });
        updateCountDownText();      //updateEverySecond
```

**startTimer()**

```
mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning = false;
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
            mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }.start();
    mTimerRunning = true;
    mButtonStartPause.setText("pause");
    mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**pauseTimer()**

```
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    mTimerRunning = false;
    mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
    mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**resetTimer()**

```
    mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    updateCountDownText();
    mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**updateCountDownText()**

```
    int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
```

and Finally **XML**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_countdown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="60sp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_start_pause"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_countdown"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="start" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_countdown"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_start_pause"
    android:text="reset"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: Welcome Tiwary.

Comment: Hey if you don't mind can we connect over any other social platforms, I'm new to Android dev maybe we could help each other more often.

Comment: @KHUSHALTiwary LinkedIn profile in bio connect me